# Clone and Copy Method Not Working When Importing Square SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, square-connect

I downloaded the sample project from GitHub, followed the instructions to basically copy and paste the SDK over into my app, but the framework is missing.

[image]

Additionally If I just drag and drop the folder with the files into my app like the GitHub said:

> Clone-and-Copy
>
> You can always just clone this repository and copy the source files
>   from the SquarePointOfSaleSDK directory into your project, but when
>   using this approach, you must manually keep the SDK up-to-date
>   yourself.

[image]

When I go to build the app I get the following error:

[image]

I event tried adding `SquarePointOfSaleSDK.h` to Linked Frameworkds and Libraries but that didn't work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clone the https://github.com/square/SquarePointOfSaleSDK-iOS repo
2. Copy the  directory into the root directory of your project. (See Fig. 1). Usually, this is the same folder that contains the `<YourAppName>.xcodeproj` file.
3. In XCode’s file explorer, drag the copied SquarePointOfSaleSDK directory into your app’s project >  Select “**Create Groups**” > 
   Check “**Add to targets**” next to your app’s target
4. Under Build Settings (see Fig. 2), Add $(SRCROOT) to the **User Header Search Path** build settings > Set it to recursively search subfolders. > Set the **Always Search User Paths** build settings flag to YES for your target
5. Use the following import declaration in any dependent header/implementation files:
   `#import <SquarePointOfSaleSDK/SquarePointOfSaleSDK.h>`

Fig 1: File explorer after adding SquarePointOfSaleSDK group and files:

[image: image of file explorer]

Fig 2: Build Settings

[image: image of build settings]

Comment: I should note that you do not need to drag the SDK folder into the root folder. Doing that with the other instructions cause a multiple import and throws redefinition errors. If you do drag to the root project and follow the instructions for Search Paths, you must not "copy the files into the project if needed".